# Published works based on questions/answers from Worldbuilding.SE

Tags: discussion

Has anyone published a game, story, or picture that's partially based on questions and/or answers from Worldbuilding.SE? The definition of publish is very loose -- it can include stories published on a personal blog. If so, please post a link to your published work as an answer to this question.

Related meta discussion: [Do we have any success stories yet? I want to read them!](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3890/171)

Comment: I think many of the users with higher reputations and had created their account long ago are likely to have had wrote stories with relations to questions they asked.

Comment: We have a nice blog on medium called the "Universe Factory" where quite a few really good short stories have been published. I cannot link to it unfortunately due to the crappy school website blocker I can't get to the page.

Comment: The blog is at https://medium.com/universe-factory

Comment: The list of fictions on the blog has been actualised and is summarised [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2559/9685). Hopefully I did not forget anyone.

Comment: I'm constantly publishing facebook comment about some of these amazing ideas!

Comment: when i publish my stuff, you'll be the first to know.  :-)