# What game is this?

Tags: discussion

I randomly ended on this stack and I'm liking what I see.

The single problem is that everyone mentions about worlds and I assume its a game or something.

Couldn't find anything on google or on this stack.

help meee , gimme a link.

Comment: Hello. Please, [take tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site. We are about building consistent worlds here. So if you are building a world for a novel, game, etc. and you have a problem with creating one part of it this is the place to go. We are a "Question and Answer" Site and belong to the StackExchange network.

Comment: this is a Q&A site for world creation, if people need help creating something in a world using science, this is NOT a game

Comment: @Cursed1701 Let's be honest, its kind of a game :)

Comment: @James it lacks offline mode, campaign, single player, and multiplayer is still barely out of the alpha, but yes

Answer (score 6):

This stack isn't about games. People ask questions for how they'll build a story world. By giving a quick run down of what they've already got, they'll ask the question to further expand on it.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

This site is not about one game. It is about creating worlds, and, frankly, some of worlds created here probably end up as game worlds*. But that's not the point.

The very point here is creation of fictional worlds (or elements of these worlds) that are internally consistent, believable, and can serve desired role in prose / game / movie etc.

---

Of course, entire Stack Exchange is a game in itself. Read [this blog entry](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/09/16/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/) to see how, why, and why it's so interesting.

---

* Sadly, [people are shy to share their published works](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3893/809) but you can read about [works in progress](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3667/809) (thanks, [James](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)!).

Comment: Well put Molot.

Comment: Also this: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/what-worlds-are-you-currently-building