# WB answers I can see in a film

Tags: discussion, answers

Are there any answers here on worldbuilding.se that inspired the plot, an scene or dialogue of a film?

I often see some answers here that would be nice to see in a film trailer in a year or two, so I wonder if that already happened.

To clarify on the scope; a *film* here is one that matches the same (or most parts of the) eligibility rules as in the [Academy Awards (RULE TWO ELIGIBILITY)](http://www.oscars.org/sites/oscars/files/91aa_rules.pdf).

Comment: You'll have a hard time getting any answers to this question... Unless an OP is involved in a film project and sees and answers this question, we'll probably never know - unless it is *really* obvious.

Comment: Nevertheless it's a good question. We put so much effort in building worlds, that it would be nice to see that landing somewhere :)

Comment: Related: [Have any answers made it into published fiction?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4260/28789), [Published works based on questions/answers from Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3893/28789) and [Do we have any success stories yet? I want to read them!](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3890/28789)

Comment: @Secespitus thanks for the links, after seeing them looks like this question will remain unanswered for a while